# WooCommerce Delivery Notes Hide Discount Row and Add Billing Address

Tags: php, woocommerce

I am using a plugin named WCDN, how can I hide the discount row? I only need the total row. And how can I insert the shipping address to the receipt?
[image]

Comment: Can you provide the screenshot of the discount row. So that we can point out

Comment: already edited sir.

Comment: You have to inspect the Discount's 'class name' using firebug or developer tool in chrome and using that class name find this in plugin page of your file and you will find the related class in a file. Go to that file and comment it.

Comment: I've already inspected it. When I hide that row, the total row also hides.

Comment: Please post that div, so that we can check it.